# graphql-tag/index has no exported member 'gql'

Tags: node.js, angular, graphql

I'm converting my Angular app REST backend to GraphQL. I'm trying to import gql from graphql-tag. I'm searching and searching and my import looks like everyone elses...

```
import { Angular2Apollo } from 'angular2-apollo';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { gql } from 'graphql-tag';
```

But the gql has the red underline indicating not found. When i run `ng serve` I get this error in cmder...

*... /node_modules/graphql-tag/index"' has no exported member 'gql'.)*

I have run many, many apollo and angular npm installs, including `npm install --save graphql-tag`, trying install whatever I'm missing, doesn't seem to matter what I install.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see it. What is happening here is your code is trying to destructure `gql` off of the object that is exported out of graphql-tag, but the error is telling you there is no exported member of this name, meaning the exported object doesn't have a method of that name, or there are more than one object exported.

If you were to look in the code for graphql-tag, you would see it probably has a few export objects or it only has one that doesnt have a method called gql, so what you need to do is take `gql` directly, ie: without destructuring it, ie: without the { }.

This will be correct: `import gql from 'graphql-tag'`

You can see this all the time depending how you export and import things from modules.

Commit to memory that every time you see { something }, it is pulling `something` off an object.

Here is some sample code to illustrate:

```
const object = {
    test: { name = 'Locohost' }
}

const { name } = object.test

console.log(name)
```

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make. I do it often, maybe not often but you know what I mean. It could happen at any moment to anyone while you're busy thinking about other stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Use the default export instead:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
```